# OpenGL - modyfing texture parameters

Tags: opengl

I have a GUI which allow to set a texture parameters using glTexImage2D. Let's assume that initially a texture is created this way:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

After that I would like to modify some parameters, here is an example:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1024, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Should I call `glDeleteTexture` and once again `glGenTextures` before modyfing texture parameters or there is no reason for doing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture parameters are state set on a previously created texture object initialized using `glTexImage` or `glTexStorage` (or their DSA counterparts). As such, deleting the texture would be moot.

Just change the texture parameters whenever you feel the need for it. *Or use **[Sampler Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler%20Object)** if you use a specific set of different parameters for a particular texture.*

Comment: In the above example glTexImage also changes texture parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that part. In terms of OpenGL those are not texture parameters, but *texture level parameters*. If using mutable storage, i.e. those created using `glTexImage` (instead of `glTexStorage`) you can respecify a texture level, without the need to delete the texture object first. For immutable storage, you must create a new texture object.